# With/Function(/etc) replacement behaviour

Tags: evaluation, scoping

Can anyone explain to me this behaviour? I've been having more than a couple of similar doubts these last weeks.

For example

```
f[_?NumericQ] := 8;
```

Now, if I do

```
With[{a = f[a]}, HoldForm@Block[{NumericQ = True &}, a]]
```

I get

```
Block[{NumericQ = True &}, f[a]]
```

And if I do

```
Block[{NumericQ = True &}, f[a]]
```

I get

```
8
```

So far so good... Another so-far-so-goodie is (notice the `:=`)

```
With[{a := f[a]}, Block[{NumericQ = True &}, a]]

8
```

Question: Can anyone help me understand why this output?

```
With[{a = f[a]}, Block[{NumericQ = True &}, a]]

f[a]
```

Could it be that `With` (`=` version) not only evaluates and replaces, but also guarantees that the replaced expression won't be reevaluated no matter what until the `With` is exited? If that's the case I wasn't expecting that. What's happening here?

**EDIT**

Question also applies to Function

```
Block[{NumericQ = True &}, #] &[f[a]]

f[a]
```

And not just those too. Everything I try behaves the same way... A couple of other examples

```
Block @@ (Hold[{NumericQ = True &}, exp] /. exp -> f[a])

With[{a := Evaluate@f[a]}, Block[{NumericQ = True &}, a]]
```

both give `f[a]`

**EDIT**

```
With[{g = h}, h = 8; Print[g] ]
```

prints 8, not h, so clearly h is reevaluated inside the `With` in this case, so `g` is not so constant.

**EDIT**

Ok, another couple of examples

```
In[10]:= ClearAll[h, f];
h := 8 /; NumericQ["a"];
f[_?NumericQ] := 8;
```

Now, both `h` and `f[a]` remain unevaluated

```
In[21]:= {h, f[a]}

Out[21]= {h, f[a]}
```

Now, with the `OwnValues` everything works as expected

```
In[17]:= With[{g = h},
 Block[{NumericQ = True &}, g]]

Out[17]= 8
```

But with the `DownValues`, it doesn't

```
In[19]:= With[{g = f[a]},
 Block[{NumericQ = True &}, g]]

Out[19]= f[a]
```

Similarly

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := 8;
g[e_] := Block[{NumericQ = True &}, e]
```

`f[a]` evaluates to `f[a]`, but weirdly

```
In[17]:= g[Unevaluated@f[a]]

Out[17]= 8

In[18]:= g[f[a]]

Out[18]= f[a]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were asking why

```
f[_?NumericQ] := 8

With[{a = f[a]}, Block[{NumericQ = True &}, a]]
```

outputs `f[a]`.

This is because of [caching](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Update.html) of the result of `Condition`s and `PatternTest`s.  Compare with this:

```
With[{a = f[a]}, Block[{NumericQ = True &}, Update[]; a]]

(* ==> 8 *)
```

Generally, making global changes that might affect the outcome of a `Condition` will have unpredictable results due to caching---unless you use `Update[]` after each change.

Please see also the last paragraph of [Controlling Infinite Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ControllingInfiniteEvaluation.html).

Comment: Szabolcs to the rescue......

Comment: Interesting, the relation of this behavior to caching wasn't obvious to me. +1.

Comment: @Leonid and Rojo: the clue was that `TracePrint` didn't show `NumericQ` being evaluated for the second time.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I also used `Trace` and saw that there was no second evaluation. I just read your answer first, and realized that without `Trace`, this wouldn't be something I'd guess right away.

Answer (score 4):

See the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/567/8).

The short answer is that, yes, `With` is designed for creating local *constants*, so once the local expressions are initialised, they won't be re-evaluated.

Using the `{a := f[a]}` notation gets around this design feature of `With`. 
To be honest, though, I have never seen it used before. It is not mentioned in the documentation, and I can't help thinking that it breaks something in subtle ways.

Of course `Block[{a = f[a], NumericQ = True &}, a]` gives a `$RecursionLimit` error, but returns `8`.

Is there a reason why `Block[{NumericQ = True &}, f[a]]` doesn't fulfil your purpose?

In response to your edit, `Block[{NumericQ = True &}, #] & [f[a]]`  doesn't give your desired output because the `f[a]` is outside the `Block` scoping construct. Again, see [Leonid's answer to the previously mentioned question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/8) as well as the other answers there.

Comment: I wanted f[a] evaluated with normal definitions (`NumericQ` meaning what it means) and afterwards (if necessary) reevaluated letting it match the ?NumericQ definition. I thought I would get that behaviour with the `With` or with a `Function` but I was clearly wrong

Comment: `With` may be designed to define constants that cannot be changed, but I definately expected `Function` to simply replace it's arguments and evaluate. Shouldn't `f[a]` be put inside the `Block` before the `Block` is even considered?

Comment: I think I've seen `SetDelayed` used in `With` discussed on SO. Maybe by Simon or Leonid.

Comment: @Mike I learned this syntax from Szabolcs, relatively recently.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TracePrint` to try to understand how evolves the evaluation step by step:

```
In[23]:= TracePrint[With[{b=f[a]},Block[{NumericQ=True&},b]]]
During evaluation of In[23]:=  With[{b=f[a]},Block[{NumericQ=True&},b]]
During evaluation of In[23]:=   With
During evaluation of In[23]:=   f[a]
During evaluation of In[23]:=    f
During evaluation of In[23]:=    a
During evaluation of In[23]:=    NumericQ[a]
During evaluation of In[23]:=     NumericQ
During evaluation of In[23]:=     a
During evaluation of In[23]:=    False
During evaluation of In[23]:=  Block[{NumericQ=True&},f[a]]
During evaluation of In[23]:=   Block
During evaluation of In[23]:=   True&
During evaluation of In[23]:=    Function
During evaluation of In[23]:=   NumericQ=Unevaluated[True&]
During evaluation of In[23]:=    Set
During evaluation of In[23]:=   NumericQ=True&
During evaluation of In[23]:=   True&
During evaluation of In[23]:=   f[a]
During evaluation of In[23]:=  f[a]
Out[23]= f[a]
```

As Verbeia said before, you can see that `NumericQ[a]` is evaluated before it goes to the `Block`. In the other hand, if you use the delayed set:

```
In[24]:= TracePrint[With[{b:=f[a]},Block[{NumericQ=True&},b]]]
During evaluation of In[24]:=  With[{b:=f[a]},Block[{NumericQ=True&},b]]
During evaluation of In[24]:=   With
During evaluation of In[24]:=  Block[{NumericQ=True&},f[a]]
During evaluation of In[24]:=   Block
During evaluation of In[24]:=   True&
During evaluation of In[24]:=    Function
During evaluation of In[24]:=   NumericQ=Unevaluated[True&]
During evaluation of In[24]:=    Set
During evaluation of In[24]:=   NumericQ=True&
During evaluation of In[24]:=   True&
During evaluation of In[24]:=   f[a]
During evaluation of In[24]:=    f
During evaluation of In[24]:=    a
During evaluation of In[24]:=    NumericQ[a]
During evaluation of In[24]:=     NumericQ
During evaluation of In[24]:=     True&
During evaluation of In[24]:=     a
During evaluation of In[24]:=    (True&)[a]
During evaluation of In[24]:=    True
During evaluation of In[24]:=   8
During evaluation of In[24]:=  8
Out[24]= 8
```

Evaluation of `f[a]` happens inside the `Block`. I changed the `With` variable to `b`, so you can see the difference, but the output is the same using `a` as variable, I don't get any `$RecursionLimit` error (using *Mathematica* 8).

Comment: I know it evaluates before the `Block` but how can I make it evaluate again inside the `Block`?

Comment: Well, it seems the right answer is with the delayed set, or with `Hold`, something like: `With[{b = Hold[f[a]]}, Block[{NumericQ = True &}, ReleaseHold[b]]]`

Comment: my bad, I wasn't clear. I want it to be evaluated both outside the block with `NumericQ` meaning it's regular meaning, and then again inside the `Block` with the redefined `NumericQ`. Your code works but it only evaluates `f[a]` inside the `Block`