# Why do subsequent evaluations seem to be stopped by a False Condition (/;)?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Exploring another problem and [this example of @halirutan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35855017#35855017), I came across an evaluation behavior I don't understand.

When `g[]` below is evaluated the first time, `ig[]` is evaluated and a message printed; on subsequent calls to `g[]`, `ig[]` is not evaluated. This can be verified with [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html).

```
ClearAll[g, ig];
g::msg = "Message";
ig[] := Module[{}, Null /; (Message[g::msg]; False)];
g[] := Module[{res = ig[]}, res /; FreeQ[res, ig]];
```

It is as if *Mathematica* decided that `ig[]` is constant and assumes it does not need to be called further.  However, each time `ig[]` is executed in the front end directly, it is evaluated, a message is printed, and it returns `ig[]`.

With the modification below, in which `ih[]` is not constant, the first four times `h[]` is evaluated the function `ih[]` is evaluated. In subsequent evaluations of `h[]`, `ih[]` is not evaluated again.

```
ClearAll[h, ih];
h::msg = "Message";
n = 2^4;
ih[] := Module[{}, n /; (n /= 2; Message[h::msg]; EvenQ[n])];
h[] := Module[{res = ih[]}, res /; FreeQ[res, ih]];
```

That is, once `n` becomes odd and `EvenQ[n]` tests `False`, the evaluation of `h[]` seems to change so that `ih[]` is no longer called from within `h[]`.

Is this right, or am I missing something? Is this how it should be?

Comment: Related, I believe, to Rojo's "guard" construct: [(5827)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5827/121), [(9536)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9536/121) [(39924)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39924/121)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use [`Update`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update.html), e.g. `Update[ig]` or `Update[ih]`, to tell Mathematica that the condition has changed and it should reevaluate `ig` or `ih`.

Also, see [(1765)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1768/45431) and [(79486)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79810/45431).