# Force evaluation of user-defined function

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Consider a function that sorts its arguments based on a function called `order`

```
Clear[f, order]
f[x_, y_] /; order[x] > order[y] := f[y, x]
order[1] = 1;
order[2] = 2;
expr1 = f[1, 2]
expr2 = f[2, 1]
(* f[1, 2] *)
(* f[1, 2] *)
```

However, let's imagine that we change the ordering function

```
order[1] = 2;
order[2] = 1;
```

Surprisingly, `expr1` and `expr2` still evaluate to `f[1,2]`

```
expr1
expr2
(* f[1, 2] *)
(* f[1, 2] *)
```

However, if we introduce `f[1, 2]` we obtain the correct result

```
f[1, 2]
(* f[2, 1] *)
```

Is there a way to force the reevaluation of `expr` to obtain `f[2, 1]`? I am looking for a function along the lines of

```
ForceEvaluation@expr1
ForceEvaluation@expr2
(* f[2, 1] *)
(* f[2, 1] *)
```

Comment: While I appreciate the accept, I'd recommend holding off for at least a few more hours. There are plenty of users who know more about _Mathematica_ than I who might be able to provide a better answer, but once an answer is accepted many people will start skipping the question entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, since I am new I did not consider this. It is certainly an obscure behaviour of Mathematica, and it would be great to hear more about it!

Comment: Related, but not as minimal an example: [(139461)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139461/121)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stumbled across the solution to this in `tutorial/ControllingInfiniteEvaluation` in the documentation. The last paragraph says:

> Some of the trickiest cases occur when you have rules that depend on complicated `/;` conditions (see "Putting Constraints on Patterns"). One particularly awkward case is when the condition involves a "global variable". The Wolfram Language may think that the evaluation is finished because the expression did not change. However, a side effect of some other operation could change the value of the global variable, and so should lead to a new result in the evaluation. The best way to avoid this kind of difficulty is not to use global variables in `/;` conditions. If all else fails, you can type `Update[s]` to tell the Wolfram Language to update all expressions involving `s`. `Update[]` tells the Wolfram Language to update absolutely all expressions.

The symbol to updated in this case is `f`, rather than `order`, but:

```
Clear[f, order]
f[x_, y_] /; order[x] > order[y] := f[y, x]
order[1] = 1;
order[2] = 2;
expr1 = f[1, 2];
expr2 = f[2, 1];
{expr1, expr2}
```

> {f[1, 2], f[1, 2]}

```
order[1] = 2;
order[2] = 1;
Update[f];
{expr1, expr2}
```

> {f[2, 1], f[2, 1]}

Clunky, but it works.